# codeigniter from helper (dash between numbers)

Tags: codeigniter-3

(Sorry for my english)

I want to ask you if it is possible to add dash into form helper.

Example:

```
B. Day: 05-01-1996
```

And this will be in input form.

```
['day']-['month']-['year']
```

Something like when you pay with card and you are entering your card numbers and every 4. number is dash or space.

```
<?php echo form_input(['name' => 'bday', 'class' => 'form-control'], ['day']-['month']-['year']); ?>
```

I want to know if this is possible in Codeigniter, and if yes can you explain me how to make it.

I do not know if I rightly explained what I want.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use regular expression instead.

Use this in your regular expression or html input pattern..

```
[0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}[ ][0-9]{4}
OR
[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}
```

You can also check some other [Here](http://html5pattern.com/Cards)